# How to get additional languages of my ipad app displayed in itunes?

Tags: objective-c, localization, itunes

I have an iPad app which has got a few additional languages. The only problem that I can't find how to list these languages under app's name on Itunes?

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

There's a section for `Localizations` in iTunes Connect.

```
Manage Your Applications / Your App 1.0 / View Details / Manage Localizations
```

Note that you can only edit these while your update or 1.0 of your app is waiting to be uploaded.

For a more in-depth explanation of Localization, refer to the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf), specifically page 62.

Comment: i have no problem with adding localized descriptions to iTunes. the problem is that the list of languages under app name stil lists only English.

Comment: yeah, but how to get additional languages listed too? i saw many apps which has several languages under icon in language section.